# Spring boot not loading the correct template and cannot debug

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to Spring boot and been following this guide:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Where the Controller looks like this:

```
`package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required=false, defaultValue="World") String name, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "greeting";
    }

}`
```

Since it is returning a String "greeting", it will look for the greeting.html. Not sure how, but I believe because of the dependency in Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

From this point, all is good. I can see the greeting.html template that is located in: src/main/resources/templates/greeting.html

Now I started to create new templates and tried to access them the same way and it seems that everything is failing.

What I did next is changed the return String of the greeting() to "greeting2" just to make sure that it is really the one mapping the view greeting.html.
But the weird thing is I can still access the greeting.html after that.

I thought it was cache issue so I cleared the browsers cache and still experiencing this.

I even changed the way the Controller method returns view and used ModelAndView object and still no luck.

I am lost, please help.
Thanks

Also.... I cannot debug. Tried Debug As Java Application at the Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

and put break point at my Controller, and it is not going to those lines.

Comment: Check few points 1) Did you added greeting2.html page. 2) Did you update return statement  return "greeting"; to  return "greeting2"; 3) Restart the application

Comment: I was forcing it to show me an error that is why I did not add greeting2.html. Did restart the app and still the same thing occurs.

Comment: In your Application class, try to annotate it with @ComponentScan("you.main.package")

Comment: @JotaFreitasJr But why? He already has [@SpringBootApplication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/SpringBootApplication.html)

Comment: I still don't know what I did wrong the first time. I recreated my project and it is working fine now.